# Sorting practice , where to get started?

Tags: sorting

I decided I wanted to mess around and try to design some sorting algorithms, look at like bubble sorting and see if I could get quick sorting working, but the first issue I was faced with is how should I store and address my data? And where should it come from?

Should I just declare an array with a couple thousand index fields, and manually enter in and randomize my data? Or should I create a stack?

How am I going to go about getting these random numbers? Surely I'm not going to have to generate thousands of them an enter them all by hand.

For the sake of simplicity I think I am just going to stick with integers.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is just with getting test cases, you can write your algorithms using HackerRank, and they have lots of test cases for you. Here is a link to all of their sorting challenges:

https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/algorithms/arrays-and-sorting

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to ask here. Can you please be specific? If the question is how you generate input to sorting, then you can definitely use randomization. If you are looking for good place to learn sorting itself, I suggest Introduction to algorithms by Cormen.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/sorting/

I like to use the above topcoder link as a reference to sorting. They have the algorithms required and it's available for free. You shouldn't need to use a textbook.

As for data input, test cases can be gotten through hackerrank, as stated in another answer, or you could write a function to randomly generate numbers.

For example, if you are using Java, you can use Random:

```
import java.util.Random;

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

     Random randNum;
     int randomNum = randNum.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

     return randomNum;
 }
```

You could then use a function like this to generate your random numbers one at a time in a loop to put into an array to sort on.

For example:

```
int toSort = 1000;
int[] arrayToSort = new int[toSort];

for(int numsToSort = toSort; numsToSort > 0; numsToSort--){
    arrayToSort[numsToSort] = randInt(0, 100);
}
```

Here, I am generating a 1000 item array with random integers between 0 and 100.

Comment: Feel free to comment with any questions, and I'll be happy to help or to expand upon my answer

Answer (score 0):

OK well I perhaps should have researched some more prior to posting, as it turns out there is a ready-made method for generating random numbers in the c# framework.So it was simply a matter of creating an array with X number of spaces and running a loop X number of times to insert a random number into that array index.

Now I've got to figure out how to code the comparison